# Maven loads Servlet API twice

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-wtp

I am getting a ClassCastException for `org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter`

In the logs I see that my `javax.servlet.Filter` is loaded twice.

Once from my local maven repository

```
[Loaded javax.servlet.Filter from file:/C:/Users/xxxx/.m2/repository/javax/servlet/servlet-api/2.5/servlet-api-2.5.jar]
```

And another one from tomcat

```
[Loaded javax.servlet.Filter from file:/C:/Apache.org/apache-tomcat-6.0.32/lib/servlet-api.jar]
```

As soon as the second version of filter is loaded I get the following exception in the server log.

```
Apr 20, 2011 2:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter struts2
java.lang.ClassCastException:    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter cannot be cast to javax.servlet.Filter
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:275)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:422)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:115)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4071)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:799)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:675)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:601)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1315)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:324)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1061)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Apr 20, 2011 2:42:21 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error filterStart
```

Here is a snippet of my `pom.xml`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <type>jar</type>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <optional>false</optional>
</dependency>
```

Thank you for looking.

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should mark the servlet-api dependency in your pom.xml as `<scope>provided</scope>` so maven won't include it in the final build. Then execute an `mvn clean package`

Comment: @fmucar I see the scope as provided. Any other idea?

Comment: does it place servlet-api in your final build in web-inf/lib? maybe child pom is overriding it

Comment: Nothing in my web-inf/lib but I see the servlet-api jar in my tomcat/lib

Comment: post your pom file. tomcat/lib normally has the servlet-api so it is pretty normal. And tell us how you deploy your application. Do you deploy war file?

Comment: I edited my post to put the pom snippet. I searched through the workspace to make sure I didn't have another pom.xml that addresses servlet-api dependency. Also, I am not deploying a war file in my local box. I am running eclipse with EE enabled so I have configured it to serve modules without publishing.

Comment: why did you add "<optional>false</optional>" to the dependency?

Comment: workspace_home\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ are you using above path for eclipse-tomcat deployment?

Comment: @fmucar I check the "Serve modules without publishing" in my Tomcat Overview page in eclipse so it doesn't publish anything to the temp file. I want to keep it this way to avoid publishing stuff. About  "<optional>false</optional>" I am not sure why it is there. Should I remove it?

Comment: Just to further clarify, I was having the same issue and I had to turn off "serve modules without publishing" to fix it.

Comment: That probably won't solve the problem for the final created package

Answer (score 3):

Trying cleaning all of the exploded wars out of your tomcat temp directory. Sometimes that garbage causes multiple versions of a class to get loaded. Especially if you've changed your pom.xml in the interim. Do this and leave the scope as `provided`